# Store a new variable using awk in my bashrc file

Tags: awk, bashrc

I am writing an `alias` for my `.bashrc` that fetches my terminals `TTY` number from my list of processes by `grep`ing the `ps` output and doing an runs an `awk` code on the result as described below:

```
alias myTTY="ps -et | grep ' ps ' | awk '{print \$2}' | head -n1"
```

What I want to do is to have the printed string stored as the new variable `TTY`. Is this possible in an `.bashrc` file or will I have to put the code in a separate `.sh` file?

Background: I have gotten a new Linux system at my new job and for some reason `echo $TTY` does not return this value like I'm used to. If anyone know a simpler way of getting this value I'm thankful but it would still be useful to find out how to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: `tty` command

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/6
$ TTY=$(tty)
$ echo $TTY                                            
/dev/pts/6
```

Comment: Thanks, then I only need to remove the /dev/ part from TTY. 
How do I execute commands that creates new variables in a .bashrc file without saving the command as a string?

Comment: `TTY=${TTY#/}` will remove the `/dev/` part.